# Django: How to fetch id in class based views?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

#### views.py

```py
from paitent.mixini import HttpResponseMixin,SerializeMixin
from paitent.models import Paitent_Details

class PaitentCRUDCBV(View, HttpResponseMixin, SerializeMixin):

   def get(self, id, *args, **kwargs):
      paitent = Paitent_Details.objects.get(id=id)
      json_data = self.render_to_serialize([paitent,])
      return self.render_to_http_response(json_data)
```

#### urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^api/json',views.PaitentCRUDCBV.as_view()),
]
```

My requirement is based on `id` i have to fetch particular row form data base,from Frontend side i am passing id in url like:**(url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/json/?id=2")**.But i am not finding id inside my class ,don't know where i am doing wrong. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query_params in view:

`def get(self, request):
    id = self.request.query_params.get('id')

    ....`

[You can get more information from documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params)

Answer (score 0):

```
1)I have edited your following code, you have to pass *request* in your function,
2)Inside the function calling request.query_params.get, you will get parameters value from the url  



from paitent.mixini import HttpResponseMixin,SerializeMixin
from paitent.models import Paitent_Details

class PaitentCRUDCBV(View, HttpResponseMixin, SerializeMixin):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      id=self.request.query_params.get('id')
      paitent = Paitent_Details.objects.get(id=id)
      json_data = self.render_to_serialize([paitent,])
      return self.render_to_http_response(json_data)
```